# После форматирования XML файла в Eclipse не могу его распарсить

Tags: java, xml

При открытии файла XML в редакторе Eclipse последний выводит его одной длинной строкой. После форматирования(в ручную или с Ctrl+Shift+F, не важно) я не могу его распарсить.
Код xml(после форматирования):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<server
    clientQ="10"
    msgQ="10"
    port="1234">
    <clients>
        <client>
            <name>Yana</name>
            <login>yanaselin</login>
            <password>1234</password>
        </client>
        <client>
            <name>Vova</name>
            <login>vovakor</login>
            <password>5678</password>
        </client>
    </clients>
</server>
```

Атрибуты сервера считываются без проблем, а дальше начинается ерунда.
Код парса:

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse("D:\\java\\workplace\\Server\\src\\main\\config\\config.xml");
root = document.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(children.getLength());
for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(children.item(i).getNodeName());
    System.out.println(children.item(i).getTextContent());
}
NodeList clients = children.item(0).getChildNodes();
System.out.println(clients.getLength());
for (int i = 0; i < clients.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(clients.item(i).getNodeName());
    System.out.println(clients.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

При выполнении в консоль выводится:

```
3
#text


clients


            Yana
            yanaselin
            1234


            Vova
            vovakor
            5678


#text


0
```

Тот же самый код на неоформатированном файле выводит:

```
1
clients
Yanayanaselin1234Vovavovakor5678
2
client
Yanayanaselin1234
client
Vovavovakor5678
```

Есть ли способ сделать файл удобочитаемым и не получить первый вариант вывода в консоль?